# Identify HTTP Verb on JAX-RS via Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, jax-rs

I am writing some code to figure out metadata about classes implemented with `JAX-RS` and I'm writing a method that takes a [`Method`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) and returns the HTTP Verb related to that method, basically figure out if it's annotated with `@POST`, `@GET`, `@PUT` or `@DELETE`.

What I currently have is this:

```
private static String extractHttpVerb(Method method) {
    if(method.getAnnotation(GET.class) != null) {
        return "GET";
    } else if (method.getAnnotation(POST.class) != null) {
        return "POST";
    } else if (method.getAnnotation(PUT.class) != null) {
        return "PUT";
    } else if (method.getAnnotation(DELETE.class) != null){
        return "DELETE";
    } else {
        return "UNKNOWN";
    }
}
```

It works fine, but I figured out that all those annotations are annotated with `@HttpMethod` and have a `value` with it's name as a String. Example:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@HttpMethod("POST")
@Documented
public @interface POST {
}
```

So I was wondering. Is there a way for me to figure out from my reference of `Method` if it's annotated by an annotation which in turn is annotated with another specific annotation?

Something like:

```
boolean annotated = method.hasAnnotationsAnnotatedBy(HttpMethod.class);
```

PS: I know that method doesn't exist, it's just to illustrate what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Annotation`s are represented by `Class`es, just like any other objects. And just like `Method`s, `Class`es can be reflected on to check for annotations. For example

```
 Annotation anno = method.getAnnotation(...);
 Class<? extends Annotation> cls = anno.annotationType();
 boolean annotHasAnnotation = cls.isAnnotationPresent(...);
```

To put it all together into one method, you could do something like the following, which still requires you to traverse all the annotations on the method

```
public static boolean hasSuperAnnotation(Method method, Class<? extends Annotation> check) {
    for (Annotation annotation: method.getAnnotations()) {
        if (annotation.annotationType().isAnnotationPresent(check)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

[...]
boolean hasHttpMethod = hasSuperAnnotation(method, HttpMethod.class);
```

If what you were trying to do was clean up your method, you could do something like

```
public static String extractHttpVerb(Method method) {
    for (Annotation annotation: method.getAnnotations()) {
        if (annotation.annotationType().isAnnotationPresent(HttpMethod.class)) {
            return annotation.annotationType().getSimpleName();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```